# Is short space combat range in Star Trek ever addressed in-universe?

Tags: star-trek

Judging by the ship sizes given and fighting ships fitting on the TV screen, most depicted combat in Star Trek happens at around 5 to 10 kilometers range. As an answer to another question states, [Federation weapons range far exceed that distance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238470/why-do-starships-have-a-limited-weapons-range-in-star-trek). Other factions that use other weapons (disruptors, for example) seem to be not much less capable, yet also tend to close the distance within the show - for example, there are multiple instances of cloaked ships appearing at point-blank range, when they were not detected prior (i.e. the commanding officer chose to position their ships there, as opposed to somewhere farther). On the other hand, in [TNG episode 4x12 "The Wounded"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wounded_(episode)), *Phoenix* is engaging a Cardassian ship at a very long range. In fact, it picks a tactic that seems much more reasonable from modern viewpoint - moves out of effective range of enemy weapons and then uses superior range of its own weapons to destroy the target. So the capability for effective long-range engagement does exist in Star Trek universe.

Of course, the *out-of-universe* reason for this is clear - ships firing at sensor blips invisible to naked eye is not as visually striking; but **is the tendency of the Enterprise (or any Federation ship, for that matter) to fight at extremely close range as opposed to using the full range of their phasers and torpedoes ever explained *in-universe*?**

Comment: Because blips firing at other blips would hold all the excitement of watching a pong tournament.

Comment: While I can't think of any example where it is explicitly spelled out, the Federation rarely enter an encounter where they **want** to fight, so closing to negotiate makes sense. As for Klingons, they often do want to fight, but are the sort to want to see the whites of their enemies eyes as they decloak and annihilate them.

Comment: @Valorum And yet *The Expanse* managed to do spacecraft combat at a distance without resorting to pong?

Comment: @Lexible - They mostly did the whole "Enemy Below" thing where you can't see the baddies at all

Comment: @Valorum For sure… although there was also sometimes visual suspense around PVCs, torpedoes, signals, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In TOS, it was very rare to show two ships shooting at each other in the same shot.

The *Enterprise* might be seen firing phasers or photon torpedos out of the frame, and then they might cut to the enemey ship being hit by the weapons fire coming from out of the frame.

Or there might be a shot of the enemy ship firing its weapons out of the frame, and then it cuts to a shot of the  exterior of the *Enterprise* being hit by the weapons fire. Or maybe a shot of the interior of the *Enterprise* bridge, with everything shaking wildly under the force of the hit.

And the stated distances in combat were given as tens of thousands or hundreds of kilometers or miles.

Pete quoted dialog from "The Enterprise Incident", "Elaan of Troyius", and
"Patterns of Force" in his answer.

In "The Changling" the *Enterprise* is hit by two energy bolts from an unknown source before Spock manages to detect the source:

> SPOCK: Unknown, Captain. Nothing within sensor range. (a third bolt approaching) Something now, Captain. Very small. Bearing one two three degrees, mark one eight. Range ninety thousand kilometres.
>
> KIRK: That's our target, Mister Sulu. Prepare photon torpedo.
> (The third bolt hits)
>
> SCOTT: Shields still holding, sir, but the drain on the engines is reaching the critical point. Ach, we lost warp manoeuvreing power. Switching to impulse.
>
> SULU: Photon torpedoes armed, sir.
>
> KIRK: Has the target changed location, Mister Spock?
>
> SPOCK: No, sir. Holding steady.
>
> KIRK: Ready photon torpedo number two, Mister Sulu.
>
> SULU: Ready, sir.
>
> KIRK: Fire.
>
> SULU: Torpedo away. (a pause, then a flash) Direct hit.
>
> SPOCK: No effect. Target absorbed full energy of our torpedo.

In "Journey to Babel"

> CHEKOV: Aye, sir. Phasers standing by. He's just hovering out there, sir.
>
> KIRK: Looking us over. We're dead as far as he knows.
>
> THELEV: You're baiting him. You're trying to lure him in.
>
> CHEKOV: Here he comes. Range decreasing. Speed dropping close to sublight.
>
> KIRK: Hold your fire, Mister Chekov.
>
> CHEKOV: Phasers locked on target. Range closing. Seventy five thousand kilometres.
>
> KIRK: Fire.
>
> (There's a satisfying flare on the viewscreen.)
>
> CHEKOV: Got him!

In "The Tholian Web" a tholian ship approaches:

> SULU: Range two hundred thousand kilometres. Velocity zero point five one C.
> (An arrow-head shaped ship has arrived.)
>
> SPOCK: Lieutenant Uhura, signal Red Alert.
>
> UHURA: Aye, sir. Red Alert. All decks, go to Red Alert.
>
> SULU: They've stopped dead, sir. Range ninety thousand kilometres and holding.

Commander Loskene agrees to wait until the next interphase to see what happens, so the Tholian ship should not change its position after the conversation:

Later, when the interphase doesn't seem to happen on schedule:

> SULU: Mister Spock, we're being fired upon.
>
> (The ship shakes to the impact of the blasts of energy.)

The *Enterprise* fires back and damages the Tholian ship.  So 90,000 kilometers is within the weapons ranges of both ships.  Later another Tholian ship appears.

> SPOCK: Distance, Mister Sulu.
>
> SULU: Just beyond phaser range, sir.

Then the two Tholian sihps start spinning a spherical energy web to trap the *Enterprise*.  A web that should have a radius of over  90,000 kilometers to be out of range of the *Enterprise*'s phasers.

The shots of the Tholian web don't make it look like it is over 180,000 kilometers in diameter, but I guess that is due to simple special effects failure and we shouldn't consider it important.

In later *Star Trek* productions most spacehip battles had the two (or more) space ships seen in the same shot and thus appearing to be be only a kilometer or two from each other.

I put that down to a sort of reverse special effects failure.  The budgets for special effects were now high enough that they could afford to show both ships in the same shot together, and thus did so, despite that it made them fight each other at distances much closer than World War Two battleships fought.

One possible in universe explanation could be that force shields were very weak in the era of TOS, so that phasers could penetrate them and damage ships even at distances of tens or hudneds of thosuands of kilometers.  But by the era of TNG energy shields were much stronger, and starships had to get within a few kilometers of each other to have any chance of penetrating the shields and damaging the enemy ships.

I have read an article online somewhere saying the out of universe reason was *Star trek II: The Wrath of Khan*.  The final battle took place within the improbably dense Mutara Nebula, where vision was reduced to about a kilometer and sensors were almost totally useless.  Thus starships had to be almost touching each other to be able to  detect each other and aim their weapons. And later movies and tv shows copied those scenes of starships fighting almost touching because they wanted their battles scenes to look as cool as those in  *Star trek II: The Wrath of Khan*, even though the in universe reason for the ships being so close was not longer applicable.

And if anyone remembers details about that article it would improve my answer.

The influence of the *Star Wars* movies with spaceships shooting at each other from close range was probably also important.

Comment: Nice answer.  Do later series have any dialog discussing ranges?  To confirm that the in-universe range is consistent with what we see in the TV camera view of two ships in one shot, or contradict it?  The only quotes in either answer have been from TOS, showing that this apparent realism problem didn't exist there.  (Maybe some of that TOS dialog was there to justify *not* having 2 ships on screen, if some of the writers or producers felt that knife-fight range would have been better.)

Comment: Your possible explanation is interesting, but the situation depicted in the TNG episode I linked in the question contradicts it - two warships are fighting at hundreds of thousands of kilometers there, and both seem to be able to deal with other's shields fine (i.e. a hit on the aft shields is enough to make the *Phoenix* reposition, and then the Cardassian ship is quickly destroyed).

Comment: @PeterCordes We do have even better evidence - there are battles in DS9 where the opposing fleets for _lines of battle_ and any ship that steps out of the line is promptly destroyed by concentrated fire from the opposition. This clearly suggests that in such large-scale fleet combat, ships can _not_ normally concentrate their fire on individual ships (unlike, say, modern naval combat), which in turn means that the effective weapon ranges of those spaceships are tiny. This fact holds regardless of "TV post processing" ("they're actually far away, but shown to be close for clarity").

Comment: Star Wars shields can't deflect too many angles at once, hence the swarm battles. https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/3zfpky/how_do_shields_work_in_the_star_wars_universe/

Answer (score 25):

Dialog in various episodes indicates ranges of tens of thousands of kilometres, sometimes hundreds of thousands.  When was it ever close range, other than in the Mutara Nebula?

Some examples:

[The Enterprise Incident](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/59.htm)

> COMMANDER: You see, Captain? Your effort is being wasted.
> KIRK: Mister Spock, distance from the Romulan vessel?
> SPOCK: One hundred and fifty thousand kilometres, Captain, and closing very rapidly.
> KIRK: Stand by, phasers. Commander, you'll forgive me if I put up a fight.
> COMMANDER: Of course. It's expected.
> SPOCK: One hundred thousand kilometres. They should commence firing at us within the next twelve point seven seconds.

[Elaan of Troyius](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/57.htm)

> KIRK: Scotty, can you give me partial power on the phaser banks?
> (Elaan enters, in the blue wedding dress and wearing the necklace.)
> SCOTT [OC]: No, sir, not a chance.
> SULU: Three hundred thousand kilometres.
> ELAAN: I want to die with you.
> KIRK: We're not going to die. Now get off the bridge.
> SULU: One hundred thousand kilometres.
> (Weapons fire hits the Enterprise)

[Patterns of Force](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/52.htm)

> SPOCK: Captain, it's an unmanned probe which seems to be carrying a warhead.
> KIRK: Stand by phasers.
> CHEKOV: Phasers ready.
> KIRK: Range, Mister Chekov?
> CHEKOV: Two thousand kilometres, closing fast.
> KIRK: Fire.

Comment: Noting that the viewscreen magnifies the distances and the cinematography makes the ships seem much closer

Comment: @Valorum Is that in-universe? Or are the images of starships essentially only *stylistically represented* nose to nose and fighting non-diagetic (i.e. to avoid the 'pong' issue you raised above).

Comment: @Lexible - It's a mixture of both, as well as the usual problem, which is that the writers and makers of the show have given this far less thought than we're doing right now

Comment: @Lexible that the viewscreens are *capable* of impressive feats of magnification is definitely shown, but not addressed in this context. What the "TV camera" does isn't really within the realm of what can be discussed in-universe.

Comment: @hobbs [Diagesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diegesis). I am not asking about magnification on screen in-universe, I am asking whether images (the ones *we see* out-of-universe) of ships literally within a ship-length or two of one another  in a face-off or combat reflect a non-diagetic magnification as a stylistic storytelling choice.

Comment: @hobbs ["Sci-fi writers have no sense of scale"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SciFiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale) is a trope for a reason. **Mandatory TV Tropes Link Warning**

Comment: I have to admit, I have next to no knowledge on what was common in the original series. It seems directors did a good job making the ships keep their distance in combat there. That said - later series have more than enough instances of ships in combat appearing close on TV screen (*not* on the bridge viewscreens), with [DS9 being probably the most characteristic example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3V_vZaNb0U).

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov that might be connected to the fact that the producers of the original series had no computers to render impressive looking ships, so showing them at the large distance they were supposed to be anyway, was way better. In contrast, the newer shows had all the fancy 3D models, so the *had* to do the [Dogfight in Space](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OldSchoolDogfight).

Comment: @Holger that much is obvious. I'm interested if it is explained somehow from in-unverse perspective.

Comment: ds9 shows several space battles between ships that appear to be at extremely close range (at least, formations of one side fly through formations of the other)

Comment: @Lexible it's also possible to imagine that there are some sort of relativistic or relativistic-like effects in play that compress or expand the perception of space and time from the perspective of whatever "camera" view is currently shown on screen. For example, two ships are actually 500,000 km apart, but appear no more than 500m apart because the picture represents what a highly spacially-compressed in-universe subspace conduit camera would see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that you guys are confusing maximum range with effective range. Two stationary targets firing at one another would have no problem sniping one another, but consider each vessel is likely performing evasive maneuvers, at full impulse (The Star Trek Voyager Technical Manual, page 13, has full impulse listed as ¼ of the speed of light, which is 74,770 km/s).

These maneuvers would be done at relativistic speeds, and the farther apart the combatants are, the more they have to compensate for needing to fire at where they predict their opponent *will be*.

For example, at 250,000 km apart, there would be a .8 second delay between where the enemey is, and where your sensors say they should be. Enemy banks right instead of left, and you just shot empty space. (Happens an awful lot on screen if you think about it.)

Close to 15,000km, and that lag shrinks to .05 seconds.

Toss in both ships zooming around eachother at full impulse, and it's a wonder anyone hits anything at all.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This makes sense, but the question was asking if something like this is ever described or acknowledged in-universe, which is to say by a character in one of the shows or movies.